# Fibonacci Recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I have just started to learn recursion. The program I'm asked to make should take a term as input, and output the corresponding fibonacci number. This is what I have so far, but it's showing an error. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
private void btnFindNumberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    int term = Integer.parseInt(txtInputTerm.getText());
    int number = fibonacci(term);
    txtOutput.setText("Fibonacci number " + term + " is " + number);
}                                             

public int fibonacci (int term) {
    if (term == 1) {
        return term;
    } else {
       int number = fibonacci(term-1) + fibonacci(term-2);
       return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you need to read the error and if you don't understand it, tell us what ti is?

Comment: Your input parameter to method `btnFindNumberActionPerformed` is wrong.

Comment: BTW Less than 40 Fibonacci numbers fit into an `int`, I suggest you use a `long` for the value. Also note that computing such a number as you have will take longer than the age of the universe.

Comment: When you go to the doctor you don't just say `I'm sick, heal me`, you also describe your symptoms. It's the same for asking any question you have about any topic, including programming

Comment: @PeterLawrey And using recursion to compute Fibonacci numbers is a bad approch because it redoes a lot of work over and over again.

Comment: @dici ... you don't send you doctor a text saying `I'm sick, what's wrong` ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have seen it used in mutli-threading examples too often.  You only need as many threads as the answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine your fibonacci term being 2. What will happen?

- term == 1 ? wrong, continue with else...
- So try calling `fibonacci(term-1)` ( = `fibonacci(1)` ) + `fibonacci(term-2)` ( = `fibonacci(0)` )

Ok, `fibonacci(term-1)` ( = `fibonacci(1)` )...

- term == 1 ? True, returning 1

Ok, `fibonacci(term-2)` ( = `fibonacci(0)` )

- term == 1 ? False, because it's zero. And it only goes downhill from there, since the numbers get negative and you never step into term == 1.

So, perhaps you might wish to think again if your criteria should really be EQUAL to one or perhaps something different.

As a more technical explanation, since someone already mentioned it in the comments: When calling a method, some data is stored on the so called "Stack". If you call, for example, method A, which calls B, then the data for (at least) two methods is stored on the Stack. If B again calls a method, which again, which again... The Stack will overflow, which is the dreaded `StackOverflowException`. Happens often when getting the return conditions wrong on a recursive method.

And as a last comment: Don't do recursive methods unless you need to. I imagine that you need to do this to learn it now, but in the future, don't forget that recursion is a very elegant concept - but only in math, not in coding, where it tends to lead to certain problems (like that one - and the fact the calculating fibonacci recursively is the worst way to do so).

Comment: This one is big, it's a `StackOverflowError`

Comment: Are you suggesting the OP is getting a StackoverFlowError as he hasn't defined fibonacci(0) ...?

Comment: Yes, I could have suggested that, but my hope was to nudge him in the right direction without having to tell that explicitly.

Comment: Ah, I see the mistake now. Thank you!

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz If you write it in a tail-recursive fashion it's fine (but slower than a loop), and certain languages like Scala are able to perform optimizations on tail-recursive functions (basically, transforming them into loops)

Comment: True enough, but honestly, I would not recommend something just because the compiler is able to fix your problems ;-) I would still suggest keeping recursion to a minimum, especially with algorithmic problems, instead of hoping that the compiler will optimize it.

Comment: In the case of Scala it's not the hope, you can make sure of it using `@tailrec`, which will cause the compilation to fail if the optimization is impossible (for example, for mutual recursivity). For Java, I quite agree unless it makes the code very clear and you know the recursion will not get too deep

Comment: @Dici,  _Lots_ of language compilers are smart enough to do tail-recursion elimination.  Scala is different because it gives you a way to tell the compiler that you _expect_ it to turn the recursion into a loop, and then it can tell you if that is not possible.  Most other compilers will not tell you whether or not the function was optimized in that way.

Comment: @jameslarge Yeah, that was pretty much my comment about `@tailrec`, saying the optimization is not just a guess from the developer, it is something you can be sure about